# How to set the last data row excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to make a macro to help me in format some files, but each file has different number of rows (but always same number of columns). I defined the last range as `99999` because i don't know how to make the macro recognize the last row with some data and stop there.

Someone can help?

Thank you

```
  Rows("1:26").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("C16").Select
    Sheets("teste").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("I3:N99999").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("I1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("P3:P99999").Select
```

Also tried and had success:

```
    Dim Nb_Rows As Integer
Nb_Rows = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("H:H"))
For i = 1 To Nb_Rows
Range("I" & i).Value = Range("H" & i).Value + Range("F" & i).Value
Next i
```

Comment: You mean you can't google "Excel VBA find last row"?

Comment: The most detailed thread I've come across so far:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba

Comment: i found something like `count` but i really don't know how to insert in the range, because i don't have a last range, so i don't know how to define it

Comment: To "construct" a range like in your 8th line that ends at the last row, Create a Variable and save the row number of the last row +1 into it (my previous comment should help with this) then use that variable in `Range("I3:N" & EndRowNumber).Select`. By the way, the "general" form of this is `Range(StartColumnLetter & StartRowNumber & ":" & EndColumnLetter & EndRowNumber).Select`. There are other less clunky ways of working with ranges, but just helping with what you've got already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this to find the last row

```
lastRow = Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Then use string contatenation to use lastRow in the range object:

```
rangeIN = Range("I3:N" & lastRow)
```

[image]

Here is the code I used for this sample program:

```
Sub SelectRange()
    Dim rangeIN As Range
    lastRow = Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rangeIN = Range("I3:N" & lastRow)
    rangeIN.Select
End Sub
```

**What exact code you will want to use though depends on the circumstances**. For instance, if you know that there will always be at least one line of data in the N column, if the last row may be in another column (like M), etc. So it depends on a few variable factors which you will have to test out to make your macro work reliably. I recommend checking out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) for more info, as suggested by Stax.

P.S. you don't need to select a range to copy and paste it. This is a common misconception and adds inefficiency. You can usually use something like this instead:

```
Sheet2.Range("A1:B2").Value2 = Sheet1.Range("A1:B2").Value2
```